# Keras: is there an easy way to mutate (shuffle) data in/out of the training set between epochs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Without arguing the pros and cons of whether to actually do this, I'm curious if anyone has created or knows of a simple way to mutate the training data between epochs during the fitting of a model using keras.

Example: I have 100 vectors and output features that I'm using to train a model. I randomly pick 80 of them for the training set, setting the other 20 aside for validation, and then run:

```
model.fit(train_vectors,train_features,validation_data=(test_vectors,test_features))
```

Keras fitting allows one to shuffle the order of the training data with `shuffle=True` but this just randomly changes the order of the training data. It might be fun to randomly pick just 40 vectors from the training set, run an epoch, then randomly pick another 40 vectors, run another epoch, etc.

Comment: To do that, I think the only way is to build a custom data_generator to fit your model. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: Here's a title to the question : "Keras: is there an easy way to mutate (shuffle) data in part of the training set within each epoch?" That might help non-native English like myself if I understood the question right.

Answer (score 9):

https://keras.io/models/model/#fit

`model.fit()` has an argument `steps_per_epoch`. If you set `shuffle=True` and choose `steps_per_epoch` small enough you will get the behaviour that you describe.

In your example with 80 training examples: you could for instance set `batch_size` to 20 and `steps_per_epoch` to 4, or `batch_size` to 10 and `steps_per_epoch` to 8 etc.

Comment: Thanks sdcbr, I will certainly try that and if it works, mark this as the answer. I also threw out this idea to on the keras github, as a possible feature to add to the fitting routines. Who knows, they might like it.

Comment: @sdcbr When we shuffle data in batches, what should be the `steps_per_batch` to make sure that the entire training data is used? the usual `num_samples/batch_size` would onlywork if we do not shuffle.

Comment: I think it would, because the data is shuffled at the start of each epoch. So num_samples/batch_size should always be the number of steps to go through all data, regardless of the ordering.

Comment: I miscalculated! batch_size * steps_per_epoch should equal the number of training examples, ofcourse. Otherwise you won't be using all training data. I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @sdcbr Thank you! Does the choice for the parameters also impact the number of epochs you should use?

Comment: Not sure, actually.

Answer (score 1):

I found that specifying both `steps_per_epoch` and `batch_size` raises error. You can find correspondent code lines in the code linked below (seek `if steps is not None and batch_size is not None:`). Thus, we need to implement a data generator in order to realize such a behavior.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/1cf5218edb23e575a827ca4d849f1d52d21b4bb0/keras/engine/training_utils.py

Answer (score 0):

The only one way (at the moment) to achieve such a result is to use a Generator:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import Sequence
import numpy as np   

class mygenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

        # read your data here using the batch lists, batch_x and batch_y
        x = [my_readfunction(filename) for filename in batch_x] 
        y = [my_readfunction(filename) for filename in batch_y]
        return np.array(x), np.array(y)
```

To obtain the behavior you want, you may change the function _*getitem*_ in order to give every time a random batch

Comment: hello. could you let me know how to use it in fit_generator()?

Comment: i have no idea of how to deal with my_readfunction()

Comment: @손상우 I don't remember where that codes comes from. My bad for not writing down a proper MVP. The idea, anyway, is that a Generator can be an input for a Keras model. The generator can be implemented in a way that it draws elements from an array in a custom way. Anyway, I would never do this again, especially when working with files: it can become quite slow because of the I/O operations